# Stored procedure in SQL Server 2008 R2 is running fine, but getting "Divide by zero" error in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012, stored-procedures, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I am trying to create an SSRS in VS and am getting a divide by zero error in VS even though the query executes fine in SQL Server and am having a bit of trouble debugging it.

The report setup in VS is pretty simple -- I am simply pulling in columns from my stored procedure, passing a year parameter so the user can choose the report window, and providing a few bits of random text to make it look nice. There are no expressions in my solution except to pull in the stored procedure columns, e.g.

```
=Fields!TOTAL_NUMBER_RECEIVED.Value
```

The stored procedure has a few instances of division, which look like this:

```
WHILE @Month_Loop < 13
BEGIN
UPDATE #Report
SET FractionField =
CAST((SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN
        DATEPART(mm,EndDate)= @Month_Loop 
        AND EndDate - StartDate <= 30
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM #YTD
    JOIN OtherTable ON #YTD.id = OtherTable.id
    GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,EndDate))
    AS FLOAT)
    /
    CAST((SELECT TotalField 
    FROM #Report 
    WHERE MonthID = @Month_Loop)
    AS FLOAT) * 100
WHERE MonthID = @Month_Loop

SET @Month_Loop = @Month_Loop + 1
END
```

The code is just returning a ratio of the "FractionField" over the "TotalField" and inserting it into a table for each month of the year.  I have a three more loops similar to this one that are nearly identical.

I've tested my stored procedure in SQL Server and it works fine but for whatever reason I consistently get this error when running the report in Visual Studio:

> An error occurred due to local report processing.  An error has occurred during report processing.  Query execution failed for dataset 'myDataset'.
>   Divide by zero error encountered. (x30)
>   The statement has been terminated. (x30)

Any idea what I could be missing?

Comment: Look at your CASE WHEN. It is getting the sum of 1 or 0. So if the CASE evaluates False, then it's returning a 0. Hence the error.

Comment: @Kramb i think you have the 0's backwards.. you can do 0 / 1 but not 1 / 0.. the `CAST((SELECT TotalField FROM #Report WHERE MonthID = @Month_Loop) AS FLOAT)` part is the issue

Comment: The 0s are backwards for this statement.  I do have another loop that has a case on the bottom also, but I am using SUM to add all of the 1s and 0s before dividing, as above.  I assume this would not be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: Changed from DATEPART to DATEDIFF.

With what I said before in mind, Your CASE WHEN will always evaluate as false. You can't subtract two dates like that. You need to use DATEDIFF on the dates and extract just the days and subtract those.

```
WHILE @Month_Loop < 13
BEGIN
UPDATE #Report
SET FractionField =
CAST((SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN
        DATEPART(mm,EndDate)= @Month_Loop 
        AND DATEDIFF(day, EndDate, StartDate) <=30
        THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
    FROM #YTD
    JOIN OtherTable ON #YTD.id = OtherTable.id
    GROUP BY DATEPART(yy,EndDate))
    AS FLOAT)
    /
    CAST((SELECT TotalField 
    FROM #Report 
    WHERE MonthID = @Month_Loop)
    AS FLOAT) * 100
WHERE MonthID = @Month_Loop

SET @Month_Loop = @Month_Loop + 1
END
```

Comment: The DATEPART fix above assumes that the dates are in the same month--when they cross into another month it is not factoring this correctly.

Separately, the query is pulling this data in correctly in SQL Server.  Is there a reason this would somehow not translate to Visual Studio?

Comment: You are right, I did not take that into consideration. My apologies, still pretty new at this. Let me see if I can fix that.

Comment: CAST(EndDate - StartDate AS INT)

Comment: Yea, haha. I guess that works too. I did change it to DATEDIFF though.

Answer (score 0):

I was testing my code using 2015 in SQL Server, and the error came in VS when I defaulted to 2016--I forgot to limit the loops for when we don't want the months that haven't happened yet.  Here is the updated code:

```
WHILE @Month_Loop < (CASE WHEN YEAR(GETDATE()) = @Year THEN MONTH(GETDATE()) ELSE 13 END)
```